# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

> `These 3 methods are to save both parent and child`

```
  public Response createMultipleChilds(PurchaseOrderHeaderDto purchaseOrderHeaderDto) {

    try {
      PurchaseOrderHeader orderDo = importDao(purchaseOrderHeaderDto);
      createParent(orderDo);
      for (int i = 0; i < orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().size(); i++) {

        orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i).setHeaderDetails(orderDo);
        createChild(orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i));
      }
      response.setStatus(200);
      response.setMessage(" both added succesfull");

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
      response.setStatus(500);
      response.setMessage("parent not added");


    } finally {
      s.close();
    }
    return response;

  }

  private void createChild(PurchaseItem purchaseItem) {

    try {
      s = sf.openSession();
      tx = s.beginTransaction();
      PurchaseItem item = new PurchaseItem();
      if (purchaseItem.getItemName() instanceof String) {
        item.setItemName(purchaseItem.getItemName());
      }
      if (purchaseItem.getItemPrice() instanceof String) {
        item.setItemPrice(purchaseItem.getItemPrice());
      }

      item.setItemCode(purchaseItem.getItemCode());
      item.setHeaderDetails(purchaseItem.getHeaderDetails());
      s.save(item);
      response.setStatus(200);
      response.setMessage(" child added succesfull");
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.commit();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
      response.setStatus(500);
      response.setMessage("child not added");
      tx.rollback();
    } finally {
      s.close();
    }
  }


  private void createParent(PurchaseOrderHeader purchaseOrderHeader) {
    try {
      s = sf.openSession();
      tx = s.beginTransaction();
      PurchaseOrderHeader order = new PurchaseOrderHeader();
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getCompany_code() instanceof String) {
        order.setCompany_code(purchaseOrderHeader.getCompany_code());
      }
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getCurrency() instanceof String) {
        order.setCurrency(purchaseOrderHeader.getCurrency());
      }
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getStatus() instanceof String) {
        order.setStatus(purchaseOrderHeader.getStatus());
      }
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getVendor() instanceof String) {
        order.setVendor(purchaseOrderHeader.getVendor());
      }
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getOrderId() instanceof Integer) {
        order.setOrderId(purchaseOrderHeader.getOrderId());
      }
      if (purchaseOrderHeader.getPurchaseItemList() instanceof List) {
        order.setPurchaseItemList(purchaseOrderHeader.getPurchaseItemList());
      }
      order.setDocument_number(purchaseOrderHeader.getDocument_number());
      s.save(order);
      response.setStatus(200);
      response.setMessage(" parent added succesfull");
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.commit();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
      response.setStatus(500);
      response.setMessage("parent not added");
      tx.rollback();
    } finally {
      s.close();
    }
  }
```

These 2 are Do classes

```
package com.sample.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterJoinTable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
@Entity
@Table(name="PurchaseItem")

public class PurchaseItem{
    @Id  
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator") 
    @Column(name="itemId")
    private int itemId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_number")
    private PurchaseOrderHeader headerDetails;

    @Column(name="itemName")
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name="itemPrice")
    private String itemPrice;

    /*@JsonIgnore(true)*/
    @Column(name="itemCode")
    private Integer itemCode;

    public Integer getItemCode() {
        return itemCode;
    }

    public void setItemCode(Integer itemCode) {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public PurchaseOrderHeader getHeaderDetails() {
        return headerDetails;
    }

    public void setHeaderDetails(PurchaseOrderHeader headerDetails) {
        this.headerDetails = headerDetails;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
    public PurchaseItem() {

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PurchaseItem [itemId=" + itemId + ", headerDetails=" + headerDetails + ", itemName=" + itemName
                + ", itemPrice=" + itemPrice + "]";
    }

}
```

and:

```
package com.sample.entity;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Filters;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="PurchaseOrderHeader")
@FilterDef(name = "join1", parameters = {@ParamDef( name = "itemId", type = "int" ),
                                         @ParamDef( name = "document_number", type = "int" )          })

@FilterDef(name = "orderFilter", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "document_number", type = "int"),
                                             })
@Filters({
@Filter(name = "orderFilter", condition = "document_number>:document_number"),
@Filter(name = "orderFilter", condition = "status=:status"),

})
public class PurchaseOrderHeader {


                @Id
                @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
                @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator") 
                 @Column(name="document_number", nullable=false)
                private int document_number;
                /*@JsonIgnore*/
                @JsonBackReference
                @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy ="headerDetails",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
                @Filters({
                @Filter(name = "join1", condition = "itemId >= :itemId"),
                @Filter(name = "join1", condition = "document_number >= :document_number")

                })
                private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList;


                @Column(name="company_code") 
                private String company_code;

                @Column(name="status") 
                private String status;

                @Column(name="vendor", nullable=false) 
                private String vendor;

                @Column(name="currency", nullable =false) 
                private String currency;

            /*  @JsonIgnore*/
                @Column(name="orderId")
                private Integer orderId;





                public Integer getOrderId() {
                    return orderId;
                }

                public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
                    this.orderId = orderId;
                }

                public int getDocument_number() {
                                return document_number;
                }

                public void setDocument_number(int document_number) {
                                this.document_number = document_number;
                }


                public String getCompany_code() {

                                return company_code;

                }


                public void setCompany_code(String company_code) {
                    if(company_code instanceof String)
                                this.company_code = company_code;
                }

                public String getStatus() {
                                return status;
                }

                public void setStatus(String status) {
                    if(status instanceof String)
                                this.status = status;
                }

                public String getVendor() {
                                return vendor;

                }

                public void setVendor(String vendor) {
                 if(vendor instanceof String )
                                this.vendor = vendor;
                }

                public String getCurrency() {
                                return currency;

                }

                public void setCurrency(String currency) {
                    if(currency instanceof String )
                                this.currency = currency;
                }

                public List<PurchaseItem> getPurchaseItemList() {
                    return purchaseItemList;
                }

                public void setPurchaseItemList(List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList) {
                    if(purchaseItemList instanceof List)
                    this.purchaseItemList = purchaseItemList;
                }

                public PurchaseOrderHeader() {

                }

}
```

These two are DTO classes

```
package com.sample.DTO;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.sample.entity.PurchaseOrderHeader;

public class PurchaseItemDto {

    private int itemId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_number")
    private PurchaseOrderHeader headerDetails;

    private String itemName;
    private String itemPrice;
    private String itemCode;



    public String getItemCode() {
        return itemCode;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public PurchaseOrderHeader getHeaderDetails() {
        return headerDetails;
    }
    public void setHeaderDetails(PurchaseOrderHeader headerDetails) {
        this.headerDetails = headerDetails;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }
    public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public PurchaseItemDto() {

    }
}
```

and

```
package com.sample.DTO;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.sample.entity.PurchaseItem;

public class PurchaseOrderHeaderDto {

    private int document_number;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy ="headerDetails",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList;

    private String company_code;
    private String status;
    private String vendor;
    private String currency;
    private String orderId;
    public String getOrderId() {
            return orderId;
        }
        public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }
        public int getDocument_number() {
            return document_number;
        }
        public void setDocument_number(int document_number) {

            this.document_number = document_number;

        }
        public List<PurchaseItem> getPurchaseItemList() {

            return purchaseItemList;

        }
        public void setPurchaseItemList(List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList) {
            if(purchaseItemList instanceof List)
            this.purchaseItemList = purchaseItemList;
        }
        public String getCompany_code() {
            return company_code;
        }
        public void setCompany_code(String company_code) {
            if(company_code instanceof String )
            this.company_code = company_code;

        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            if(status instanceof String)
            this.status = status;
        }
        public String getVendor() {
            return vendor;
        }
        public void setVendor(String vendor) {
            if(vendor instanceof String)
            this.vendor = vendor;
        }
        public String getCurrency() {
            return currency;
        }
        public void setCurrency(String currency) {
            if(currency instanceof String)
            this.currency = currency;
        }
        public PurchaseOrderHeaderDto() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
```

> ```
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "sagar": not a valid Integer value;
> ```
>
> nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "sagar": not
>   a valid Integer value
>        at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain:
>   com.sample.DTO.PurchaseOrderHeaderDto["purchaseItemList"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.sample.entity.PurchaseItem["itemCode"])]

Comment: Please provide sample request. I would say that entities are not needed, but maybe someone who starting needs full example.